# Bokeh "show" giving AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'references'

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh function which plots a Horizontal bar chart. I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-b0fece870a18> in <module>()
----> 1 show(Show_NameBased_Chart(out_dict))

/home/rgupta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/util/api.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    188         @wraps(obj)
    189         def wrapper(*args, **kw):
--> 190             return obj(*args, **kw)
    191 
    192         wrapper.__bkversion__ = version

/home/rgupta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/io/showing.pyc in show(obj, browser, new, notebook_handle, notebook_url)
    126 
    127     if obj not in state.document.roots:
--> 128         state.document.add_root(obj)
    129     return _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new, notebook_handle=notebook_handle)
    130 

/home/rgupta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/document/document.pyc in add_root(self, model, setter)
    241             self._roots.append(model)
    242         finally:
--> 243             self._pop_all_models_freeze()
    244         self._trigger_on_change(RootAddedEvent(self, model, setter))
    245 

/home/rgupta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/document/document.pyc in _pop_all_models_freeze(self)
    921         self._all_models_freeze_count -= 1
    922         if self._all_models_freeze_count == 0:
--> 923             self._recompute_all_models()
    924 
    925     def _recompute_all_models(self):

/home/rgupta/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/document/document.pyc in _recompute_all_models(self)
    929         new_all_models_set = set()
    930         for r in self.roots:
--> 931             new_all_models_set = new_all_models_set.union(r.references())
    932         old_all_models_set = set(self._all_models.values())
    933         to_detach = old_all_models_set - new_all_models_set

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'references'
```

It seems to be only coming from the `show()` function, but at the same time if I pass `components()`, I get my output.

Following is the code along with a data snippet:

```
def Show_NameBased_Chart(in_dict):

    source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        Count = [val.get('size') for val in in_dict.values()],

#         Unique_guests = Transaction_data[Transaction_data.chain_id == CID]\
#         .groupby('merchant_id').user_id.nunique().tolist(),

        Sales = [val.get('amount_spent') for val in in_dict.values()],

        ID  = [val for val in in_dict.keys()],

#         Name  = Transaction_data[Transaction_data.chain_id == CID]\
#                 .groupby('name').sum().index.astype(str).tolist(),

        AVG = [val.get('avg') for val in in_dict.values()],

    ))

    ID = [val for val in in_dict.keys()]

#     Name  = Transaction_data[Transaction_data.chain_id == CID]\
#                 .groupby('name').sum().index.astype(str).tolist()

#     Label = Transaction_data[Transaction_data.chain_id == CID].location.unique()[0]

    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=
#     #     ("(x,y)", "(@lat, @lon)"),
#         ("Merch_ID", "@ID"),
#         ('Revenue','Rs @Sales{0,0.000}'),
#         ("Visits","@Count"),
#         ('Avg Val/Tr','@AVG'),
#         ('Mode','@Mode'),
#         ("Unique_Visitors", "@Unique_guests")
        """
    <div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 10px;">Merch_Id:</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">@ID</span>
        <div>

        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 10px;">Revenue:</span>
            <span style= font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;>&#x20B9;</span> 
            <span style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">@Sales{0,0.000}</span>
        <div>
    </div>
    """
    )


    p = figure(y_range= ID)
    # p.background_fill_color = None
    # p.background_fill_alpha = None
    # labels = LabelSet(x='Count', y='ID', text='Count', level='glyph',
    #                y_offset=5, render_mode='canvas',source=source)
    p.add_tools(hover)
    p.grid.grid_line_color = None
    p.xaxis.visible = None
    p.yaxis.axis_line_color = None
    p.xaxis.axis_line_color = None
    p.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None
    p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
    p.outline_line_alpha = 0.2
    H_1= HBar(y='ID',right='Sales',height = 0.5,fill_color="#6C69EB")
    # H_2 = HBar(y='ID',right='Sales',height = 0.5)
    p.add_glyph(source, H_1)
    # p_2 = p.add_glyph(source, H_2)


    # p.add_layout(labels)
    show(p)
in_dict = {u'1009': {u'Avg': 408.1859554880508,
  u'amount_spent': 185851,
  u'size': 444,
  u'users': [216765,
   632270,
   416138,
   267154,
   220339,
   346041,
   657993,
   658316,
   576653,
   658567,
   658406,
   658546]},
 u'1056': {u'Avg': 436.19081688035646,
  u'amount_spent': 87690,
  u'size': 311,
  u'users': [213761,
   647666,
   639524,
   562168,
   164913,
   645767]},
 u'1103': {u'Avg': 169.83717357910908,
  u'amount_spent': 12734,
  u'size': 69,
  u'users': [370590,
   353842,
   617525,
   339285,
   658440]},
 u'1105': {u'Avg': 260.63440860215053,
  u'amount_spent': 15814,
  u'size': 56,
  u'users': [187569,
   575770,
   91651,
   19981,
   8966,
   19863
   ]}
```

I can't find any apparent reason, why this is happening. Using the components function, I get my `script`,`div`; which I can plot.

Comment: Can you whittle things down to a complete minimal script that reproduces? I'd like to run something to take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your entire script and it ran without error (I had to import all required libraries). It seems you have called your function wrong -

`show(Show_NameBased_Chart(out_dict))`

You are using the output of function in show method, however your mentod doesn't output anything, rather it uses `show()`. The correct way to call the function will be -

`Show_NameBased_Chart(out_dict)`

It will generate the graph.